# Problem with .cbr comics

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cbr

I have several .cbr comic files that I downloaded and am now unable to open. I have downloaded at least 5 different comic book viewers (including comix) in Ubuntu through the package manager and downloading off websites and all of the programs are unable to open these files. I have also tried to rename the file from X.cbr to X.zip then extract the file but only the extra files within are extracted and it is unable to extract the image files.

Does anyone have any idea how to get this comics to work in either windows or Ubuntu? I'm worried that they haven't been compressed properly and I will never be able to access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.cbr` uses RAR as its compression. Install `unrar`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's quite common for `.cbr` files to actually be `.zip`, as some people don't seem to understand what the last letter in `.cbr`/`.cbz` is supposed to mean!

Answer (score 0):

If you are want to read the comic then download this software http://comicrack.cyolito.com/.

If you want to extract the content of the package use 7zip